# How should PHP FPM be monitored for max_children being exceeded?

Tags: php, monitoring, php-fpm

I've set up the PHP-FPM and Nginx status output with the intent of monitoring for max_children being exceeded on a particular pool. I am, however, unable to load the status output when max children has been reached. Rather it queues the request until a child has finished.

What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

PHP logs this particular event, (along with many other abnormal things) so you should also watch its logs.

For example:

> ```
> WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it.
> ```